# Android NavigationView colors strange behaviour

Tags: android, navigation-drawer

I'm upgrading my android application from SDK 22 to SDK 23.

I just changed library versions to the newer one and my NavigationView changed. There is two squares appeared when item is selected and I don't know how to remove them.

[image]

**Here is how it looks like before upgrade**

[image]

Here is the part of my `activity.xml`

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways" />

        <Button
            android:visibility="@integer/test_button_visibility"/>

        <android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <!-- A RecyclerView with some commonly used attributes -->
            <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                android:scrollbars="vertical"/>
        </android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <!-- The main content view -->
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                  xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"

                  tools:context=".MainActivity">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/informationTextView"
            android:visibility="gone"/>
    </LinearLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
        android:layout_width="240dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
        android:dividerHeight="0dp"
        android:theme="@style/NavigationDrawerTheme"
        app:menu="@menu/navigation_drawer_menu_items"
        app:itemTextColor="@color/text_color"/>
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

How can I remove them?

**UPDATE**

Here is my Theme

```
<style name="NavigationDrawerTheme" parent="Widget.Design.NavigationView">
    <item name="android:textSize">14sp</item>
    <item name="android:background">@color/white_text</item>
</style>
```

Comment: Have you tried using `layout_width="wrap_content"` ? for navigationview?

Comment: @LinX64 tried it right now, it is not helped

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Got it.Check this link:** http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/AppBarLayout.html

> This view depends heavily on being used as **a direct child within a
>   `CoordinatorLayout`**. If you use `AppBarLayout` within a different
>   `ViewGroup`, **most of it's functionality will not work.**

So, just add that `AppBarLayout` inside a `CoordinatorLayout` and then it should work.

Remember, don't forget to add:

```
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
```

In your contents and take a look at this example as well: http://github.com/chrisbanes/cheesesquare

Then, you're ready to go.

**Edit:** I saw it's working by removing that **Style**, remove it and then it should work.

```
<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
        android:theme="@style/NavigationDrawerTheme"
        app:itemTextColor="#b30707"
        app:menu="@menu/drawer" />
```

Comment: Thanks for answering. I put AppBar into CoordinatorLayout but it does not help. Here is my final activity.xml https://gist.github.com/c0rp-aubakirov/1f08f6b31dd0c728b5d1

Comment: Check this out: http://paste.ofcode.org/pswcwAkwNzNvEhzFju8wcf everything seems to be good right now.

Comment: Unfortunately it does not help, squares are still there

Comment: What about deleting `android:background` from that Style?Otherwise, i think better to check your java codes too because that worked for me.

Comment: Hurray, I resolved the problem by remove `@style/NavigationDrawerTheme`. Thank you very much for deep help and investigation. Could you please update you answer with the steps we did and final thing that resolved the problem

Comment: Sure, glad to hear it is working, i fixed the both issues :)

Answer (score 1):

Do you have a custom NavigationDrawerTheme? If so, could you provide it? By default, "After a list item is selected, that item changes color to match the app’s primary color (or #000000 100%) to indicate selection" (from http://www.google.com/design/spec/patterns/navigation-drawer.html#navigation-drawer-content)

It looks like the dark grey squares are the result of the list item being selected, but for some reason the hightlight isn't being shown across the full item.

Comment: The problem was my custom theme